# Stationary distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I know that for a Finite state Markov chain, it is true that there is either one or infinitely many stationary distributions. For a countable Markov chain, it may be true that there does not exist any stationary distribution, for example a counting process i.e Poisson process. But is a countable state space guaranteed at least one stationary distribution when the chain is aperiodic?

Please someone explain.

Comment: No.  Consider an M/M/1 queue with $\lambda > \mu>0$. This is an irreducible Markov chain but there is no steady state.  In discrete time, you can consider a similar birth-death chain on $\{0, 1, 2, ...\}$  with a probability of increasing more than decreasing, and this is irreducible and aperiodic, and there is no stationary distribution.  Just assume there is, write equations for $p_n$ in terms of $p_0$, then show they cannot sum to 1.

Comment: how is this chain aperiodic, i can understand since the arrival rate is more than the service rate the infinite series diverges and hence no stationary dist. but how is the chain aperiodic

Comment: The notion of "periodic" and "aperiodic" only apply to discrete time chains.  Do you agree?  For discrete time birth-death chains, they are aperiodic whenever there is a self-transition, like a transition from 0 to 0.

Comment: yes,because have to take g .c.d

Comment: what does a self loop indicate in this birth death process..

Comment: Consider a random walk on the integers, starting at $0.$ Move one unit left, don't move, or move one unit right with respective probabilities 1/6, 1/6, 4/6. Aperiodic. No stationary distribution because probability "escapes to infinity."

Comment: i understand, Brucet and Michael